# tuple with as many None as input argument?

Tags: python, tuples

Is it possible without creating any intermediary list or set to have function that takes integer as input and then create tuple with as many None as input integer.

```
def create_none_tuple(x):
# say if x = 3 then function should return (None,None,None)
    pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible by multiplying a `tuple` by an `int`:

```
def create_none_tuple(x):
  return (None,) * x

print(create_none_tuple(3))
```

Output:

```
(None, None, None)
```

For anything other than primitives, however, this can lead to errors, e.g.:

```
def create_list_tuple(x):
  return ([],) * x

lt = create_list_tuple(3)
print(lt)        #  =>  ([], [], [])
lt[0].append(1)  #  modifying one of them is modifying all of them
print(lt)        #  =>  ([1], [1], [1])
```

In this case it's better with a generator expression:

```
def create_list_tuple(x):
  return tuple([] for _ in range(x))

lt = create_list_tuple(3)
print(lt)        #  =>  ([], [], [])
lt[0].append(1)  #  only modifies the first
print(lt)        #  =>  ([1], [], [])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```py
x*(None,)
```

Returns a tuple with X's None's.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the "fastest" way would be for reasonable values of `n`, but one way is with a generator:

```
def create_none_tuple(n):
    return tuple(None for i in range(n))
```

Or more naturally with `itertools`:

```
def create_none_tuple(n):
    return tuple(itertools.repeat(None, n))
```